# select count products

Tags: php, shopping-cart, oscommerce

i have items, shoes products_tax_class_id =1, bag products_tax_class_id =2, pen products_tax_class_id =3, pencil products_tax_class_id =1 in  shopping card.

```
$result = tep_db_query("select count(*) as tax_check from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " where products_tax_class_id = '3' and products_id = '".$items[$i]['id']."'");
while ($get_now = tep_db_fetch_array($result)){
   if ($get_now['tax_check'] > 0)
```

if i echo results, prints and returns 0, 0, 1, 0 (i have 4 row) values. i want to see whether is there a 1 value, return of 4 row?

Comment: i still don't get what you are asking, if you make a select count query with actual id it will return only the class for products wich has id = '3', one per line because you come from a loop.

Comment: thats way i do not understand. i expect one line with value 1, because there is only one product. but when i try to print all the rows, if the rows have different product_tax_class_id 2 or 1, returns 0 value. so i can not write else statement. i do smth wrong but i can not find. if i could retrieve value 1 i write do ths and else do that.

Comment: this is because your are making a query in a loop so count will be 0 if 0 matches are returned

Comment: than what will be the correct code? i want to count (fast sql style) all the products and if there is a product with products_tax_class_id =3 i should be able to write else statement with result. (sorry my english)

Comment: i made an answer down here, please check

Answer (score 0):

When using `SELECT COUNT(*)` you should essentially get one row returned. Depending on how large your database is you may want to debug by removing the `count()` option from the query and do something like:

```
while ($get_now = tep_db_fetch_array($result))
{ 
    print_r($get_now)
}
```

This will give you an idea where everything comes from.

Answer (score 0):

then i would rather suggest you to change this `fetching` function to something wich will count rows

```
$result = tep_db_query("select * from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " where products_tax_class_id = '3' and products_id = '".$items[$i]['id']."'"); 
$get_now = mysql_num_rows($result); 
if ($get_now > 0) 
{
    //we've found it
}
else
{
   //not found
}
```

**NOTE** i used `mysql_num_rows` because `oscommerce` doesn't have a declared function for this

`UPDATED`

if you want to get all products and check if they have `tax_class_id = '3'` you can fetch them all and then selecting.

```
$result = tep_db_query("select * from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " where products_id = '".$items[$i]['id']."'"); 
if($get_now = tep_db_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($get_now['products_tax_class_id'] == '3') 
    {
        //this product have class = 3 do something
    }
    else
    {
       //this product haven't class = 3 do something else
    }
} else {
    //this is just a check for wrong products_id you can avoid this else since products are already in the shopping cart and it's not possible they have wrong products_id
}
```

Comment: fabio, none of them works. all the rows are coming like shoe 1, bag 2, pen 3, pencil 1. in my shopping card i have 4 items in example . if there is any item with products_tax_class_id != 3 { do this } else { do that } works perfect. i delete the item with products_tax_class_id = 3, still goes {do that}. since all the rows are coming and it can not see anything about products_tax_class_id = 3, and passes to second else statement. i need how many items have in my shopping card, any of the item has products_tax_class_id has not 3 { do this } else {do that}?

Comment: can u please edit your question and explain me this because i didn't understand what you are trying to explain

Comment: :) $items[$i]['id'] is changable. shows the items in shopping card. can be 0-100. we select items from shopping card. check their tax_class_id's.

sometimes there are items with tax_class_id =3, sometimes not. 

if there is any item with tax class _id is not 3, execute else command ?

Comment: ok if i understood what you are looking for so my new update should do what you need, please check it and let me know

Comment: fabio ths does not work, looks first product, it's tax class is not 3, writes (this product haven't class = 3 do something else), looks second product its tax class is 3, writes (this product have class = 3 do something). writes results product by product. what i need is to look all the products in shopping card suddenly if there is any product with tax class 3, to do smth, if not to do else statement.